# Hitting error on SignalR GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext

Tags: notifications, signalr

I had this working Friday last week and have not changed any code.
I can see that the SignalR Hubs are wired on client and the Application Start.  I verified paths, etc.

**When I get here, at the GetHubContext**

```
public class NotificationController
    {
        public static Task SendNotification(Guid id, int count)
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            return context.Clients.All.Notification(id, count);
        }
    }
```

**I am getting an error:**

System.MissingMethodException occurred
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings.set_MaxDepth(System.Nullable`1)'.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonNetSerializer..ctor(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonNetSerializer..ctor()
  InnerException:

I have ^NOT changed any assemblies since originally adding SignalR for use.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What version of Json.NET are you running?  Is it possible an old version is getting picked up?

Comment: What version of everything are you using.

Comment: I am using NuGet to get the latest and load in SignalR, and dependencies such as Newtonsoft.  
The .NET version is 4.0.
VS 2012 for development.
The environment for the Web App is Sitecore, but this is my second time making SignalR functional in Sitecore and it went fine (until yesterday).  I was thinking there might be a conflict in Hubs, as we are using another Notification System (Telligent Community's Notification listener) to prompt an ASHX in Sitecore that kicks off the Notification in the Controller to the Hub, however, they do not share a domain.